# onclick function javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a textarea and 3 buttons and I need to align text with this 3 buttons: left, center, right

```html
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">LEFT</button>
<script>
  function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myP").style.textAlign = "left";
  }
</script>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">CENTER</button>
<script>
  function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myP").style.textAlign = "center";
  }
</script>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">RIGHT</button>
<script>
  function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myP").style.textAlign = "right";
  }
</script>
<textarea name="textarea" id="myP" rows="10" cols="40"></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: So whats your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
  function myFunction(align) {
    document.getElementById("myP").style.textAlign = align;
  }
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction('left')">LEFT</button>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction('center')">CENTER</button>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction('right')">RIGHT</button>
</script>
<textarea name="textarea" id="myP" rows="10" cols="40"></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks bro god bless you